How to implement drag and drop between two CollectionViews in Maui
I am trying to implement drag and drop between two CollectionViews in Maui project.
In my example, I have a collection of Songs in the first CollectionView and a Playlist group in the second collection. The Song CollectionView looks like this:
        <CollectionView
            Grid.Row="2"
            Margin="0,4"
            EmptyView="You have no songs in your library!"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Songs}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="m:Song">
                    <SwipeView android:SwipeView.SwipeTransitionMode="Reveal">
                        <SwipeView.RightItems>
                            <SwipeItems SwipeBehaviorOnInvoked="Close">
                                <SwipeItem
                                    BackgroundColor="Pink"
                                    Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:PlayListViewModel}}, Path=FavoriteCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                    Text="Favorite" />
                            </SwipeItems>
                        </SwipeView.RightItems>
                        <Frame Margin="4" Padding="4">
                            <cell:SongArtist />
                            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <DragGestureRecognizer
                                    CanDrag="True"
                                    DragStartingCommand="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:PlayListViewModel}}, Path=DragStartedCommand}"
                                    DragStartingCommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Frame>
                    </SwipeView>


                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

The Playlist CollectionView looks like this:
        <CollectionView
            Grid.Row="5"
            Margin="0,4"
            EmptyView="You have no songs in your playlist!" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding PlayList}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="m:Song">
                    <SwipeView android:SwipeView.SwipeTransitionMode="Reveal">
                        <SwipeView.RightItems>
                            <SwipeItems SwipeBehaviorOnInvoked="Close">
                                <SwipeItem
                                    BackgroundColor="Red"
                                    Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:PlayListViewModel}}, Path=DeleteCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                    Text="Delete" />
                            </SwipeItems>
                        </SwipeView.RightItems>
                        <Frame Margin="4" Padding="4">
                            <cell:SongArtist />
                            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <DropGestureRecognizer AllowDrop="True" DropCommand="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:PlayListViewModel}}, Path=SongDropped}" />
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Frame>
                    </SwipeView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

The DragStartedCommand does fire. The SongDroppedCommand does not. Here is the code in my ViewModel:
        [RelayCommand]
        void DragStarted(Song song)
        {
            dragged_song = song;
            Songs.Remove(song);
            Debug.WriteLine($"DragStarted {song.Name}");
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        void SongDropped(Song song)
        {
            PlayList.Add(song);
            Debug.WriteLine($"SongDropped");
        }

Not sure why the SongDroppedCommand isn't firing.
Thanks in advance!

Your DropGestureRecognizer does not specify a CommandParameter

I tried DropCommandParameter={Binding .}. That didn't work. Do I need to set the reference to something from the Song CollectionView?

I also tried this: DropCommandParameter="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:PlayListViewModel}}, Path=Dragged_song}". Still not working,

If you don’t want to pass a parameter then modify your command to not accept a parameter

Appreciate your comments - but I simply can't get it to work. Never hitting the SongDroppedCommand

Did you remove the parameter?  If the signature of the command method does not match exactly the binding will not work

Also, the path should be SongDroppedCommand

Thank you! I have stared at this too long! One last question, what should I pass as the parameter? {Binding .} doesn't work (it is null).

I don’t think you need one.  Remove it from the method signature

See comments. With @Jason help, that was the answer.
